# What is "brightness value" in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, exposure, lightroom-5, brightness

Lightroom shows me a "brightness value" for each of my photos:

[image]

I notice that it's negative for night photography and positive for daytime photos, but I don't know how it's computed. Is it the average or median pixel value in the image? In other words, an indication of where the photo falls in the spectrum between high- and low-key images?

Can I use the brightness value to compare images, or make them equally bright perceptually? Are there other uses for this value?

Comment: Did you check if it is in the EXIF? Maybe it's not *from* Lightroom, just shown there.

Comment: Good question. I opened the ARW in Sony's Image Data Converter, but the properties did not have a field for this.

Comment: In other words, it seems to be synthesized by LR.

Comment: Sony's software may not expose all EXIF fields. Use EXIF Tool for that, it is definitely **not** created by Lightroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level, this is an EXIF value that represents the [APEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APEX_system) average luminance value of a scene. Luminance, in this case, is basically the ***intensity*** of light travelling travelling towards the camera. This is why it's typically positive for a daytime shot, because there is much more light present, reflecting off of the surface of the subjects.

The [EXIF standard](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf) (in Annex C) explains the usage in reference to exposure value.

Ev = Av + Tv = Bv + Sv

Where Ev is "Exposure Value", Av is "Aperture Value", Tv = "Time Value" (shutter speed), Bv is "Brightness Value", and Sv is "Sensitivity Value" (film speed). So, its basically a way of calculating exposure and is recorded in the image EXIF for reference.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand this equation, though. Shouldn't it be exposure = aperture * time * ISO, so taking logarithms, you'll end up with Ev = Av + Tv + Sv.

Comment: @KartickVaddadi - Exposure value has a meaning, which isn't 'exposure' as you're using it. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_value for some details.